# highstocks - get current Data (Extremes min/max)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have two date-input-field, where I want to show the Extremes (min/max) of my current Highstocks-Chart.
So exactly like, what we already have with the rangeSelector.

How to get these data?

I tried

```
chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
                events: {
                    selection: function (event) {
                        console.log('xAxisMin', event.xAxis[0].min);
                    }
                }
            }
```

but it´s not working. It´s not showing me any log in the console. Same, when I swap the event `selection` to `load` for example. Same when I tried getExtremes

Any other ideas how to get the data?

Comment: How are you trying to trigger the functionality (the `console.log`)? By clicking a button in the range selector? When do you want this to happen?

Comment: yep, for example connected with a click event. It´s not working either. All in all i want to get access to the data, save it to use it in my scope (angularjs)

Comment: You need to refer to chart (kept in this reference). Use this.xAxis[0].min